# CComPtr and std::shared_ptr interoperability

Tags: c++, com, shared-ptr

Consider following scenario. There is a ATL wrapped C++ class (`CMyComClass` which implements `IMyComClass`), this class is used in async operations so it (should derive) derives from `std::enable_shared_from_this` to provide `shared_from_this()` (instead of passing `this` to async function) which will ensure that when the async operation is invoked the object still exists. On the other hand there is a COM interface which, for example can ask for the above class to be returned as com object, something like `get(IUnknown** myobject)` or `addObject(IUnkown* mynewobject)` to add the object. At this situation I'm in a deadlock, I cant just take raw pointer from the COM and assign to the `shared_ptr` since I do not transfer the ownership, and the reference counting of `shared_ptr` will be wrong since it doesnt count previous COM references, in addition and increase in `shared_ptr` count will not affect the `CComPtr` ref count, meaning the pointer could be destroyed any time. In addition there are member functions of `CMyComClass` which could create, for example, `std::async` operation, passing `this` into it, again, the wrapping COM could be destroyed and I will be left with dangling pointer. Is there a way to overcome this problem? Is there an equivalent of `shared_from_this` on `IUnknown`. 
 Yes, I know, the design is flawed and no, I cant change it now
EDIT001:
I think I overcomplicated the question.
Lets start from the root problem.
Consider following COM class

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyComObject
    : public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
      public CComCoClass<CMyComObject, &CLSID_MyComObject>,
      public IDispatchImpl<IMyComObject, &IID_IMyComObject, &LIBID_ATLProject2Lib, /*wMajor =*/1, /*wMinor =*/0>
{
public:
    CMyComObject() { m_pUnkMarshaler = NULL; }

    DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_MYCOMOBJECT)

    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CMyComObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IMyComObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_AGGREGATE(IID_IMarshal, m_pUnkMarshaler.p)
    END_COM_MAP()

    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()
    DECLARE_GET_CONTROLLING_UNKNOWN()

    HRESULT FinalConstruct()
    {
        m_asyncTask = std::async(std::launch::async, [self{this}]() { std::cout << typeid(self).name() << std::endl; });
        return CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler(GetControllingUnknown(), &m_pUnkMarshaler.p);
    }

    void FinalRelease() { m_pUnkMarshaler.Release(); }

    CComPtr<IUnknown> m_pUnkMarshaler;

private:
    std::future<void> m_asyncTask;
};
```

Note the `std::async` in the `FinalConstruct` (not most suitable place, but pretend it is a regular COM method), `async` is called, task is scheduled, then the instance (instance of COM object) is destroyed, for example because reference count of the instance dropped to zero. Obviously the scheduled task will fail, lets say with access violation. How one would prevent it from happening?
EDIT002: just for lulz
Voila, the solution!

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyComObject
    : public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
      public CComCoClass<CMyComObject, &CLSID_MyComObject>,
      public IDispatchImpl<IMyComObject, &IID_IMyComObject, &LIBID_ATLProject2Lib, /*wMajor =*/1, /*wMinor =*/0>
{
public:
    CMyComObject()
        : m_pUnkMarshaler(nullptr), m_self(this, [](CMyComObject* p) {
              // check if still have COM references
              if(p->m_dwRef == 0)
                  delete p;
          })
    {
    }

    DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_MYCOMOBJECT)

    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CMyComObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IMyComObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_AGGREGATE(IID_IMarshal, m_pUnkMarshaler.p)
    END_COM_MAP()

    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()
    DECLARE_GET_CONTROLLING_UNKNOWN()

    HRESULT FinalConstruct()
    {
        m_asyncTask = std::async(
            std::launch::async, [self{SharedFromThis()}]() { std::cout << typeid(self).name() << std::endl; });
        return CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler(GetControllingUnknown(), &m_pUnkMarshaler.p);
    }

    void FinalRelease() { m_pUnkMarshaler.Release(); }

    ULONG InternalRelease()
    {
        if(m_dwRef > 0)
        {
            _ThreadModel::Decrement(&m_dwRef);
        }
        // Dont let COM delete the instance if there is shared ptrs in the wild
        return m_dwRef + m_self.use_count();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<CMyComObject> SharedFromThis() { return m_self; }

    CComPtr<IUnknown> m_pUnkMarshaler;

private:
    std::future<void> m_asyncTask;
    std::shared_ptr<CMyComObject> m_self;
};
```

It would be nice and elegant solution which works great. However, the class itself holding one reference to the object, so the deleter of the `std::shared_ptr` will never kick in. Alas! Do the right thing and get the stuff out of COM class and then keep the extracted stuff as `shared_ptr` in the COM class.

Comment: You are free to specialise std templates for user-defined classes. In this context, IMyComClass is a user defined class, so just write the appropriate wrapper specialisation of std::shared_ptr

Comment: @RichardHodges, @Niall, I think you guys missing one important point, if I derive my class from `enable_shared_from_this` the instance must be created by, for example, `std::make_shared`. however, since it is a COM class it could be (and most likely will be) created by `CreateInstance` or `new ActiveXObject`. How the `enable_shared_from_this` would work in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have mentioned, COM has pretty strict rules for using interfaces across threads, and you're just inviting bugs by not following those rules. This is one of the many reasons that many COM developers create their core logic as C++ classes and then wrap those C++ classes in a thin COM object. This is my recommendation. Your core object should have nothing that is COM aware. If it currently has data members that are other COM interface pointers, do the same thing -- extract that child object into a C++ class and provide a COM wrapper for the child object that is owned by the COM wrapper of the parent object.

```
class CMyObject : std::enable_shared_from_this
{
public:
    void Startup()
    {
        // non-COM stuff
        auto self = shared_from_this();
        m_asyncTask = std::async(std::launch::async, [self]() {
             std::cout << typeid(self).name() << std::endl;
        });
    }
private:
    std::future<void> m_asyncTask;
}

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyComObject
    : public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
      public CComCoClass<CMyComObject, &CLSID_MyComObject>,
      public IDispatchImpl<IMyComObject, &IID_IMyComObject, &LIBID_ATLProject2Lib, /*wMajor =*/1, /*wMinor =*/0>
{
    ...
    HRESULT FinalConstruct()
    {
        m_internal = make_shared<CMyObject>();
        m_internal->Startup();
        // COM stuff
        return CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler(GetControllingUnknown(), &m_pUnkMarshaler.p);
    }
    ...
private:
    shared_ptr<CMyObject> m_internal;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sure it is the right (and obvious) thing to do. But it implies HUGE amount of work, my class somewhat more complicated than the one in the example. I was looking for some clever workaround for this problem, but I dont see any possibility to solve it except the one you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward approach would be not to mix C++ and COM reference counters and to create a thin C++ wrapper object for COM interface that may be itself used in async operations:

```
class t_MyComClassWrapper: std::enable_shared_from_this< t_MyComClassWrapper >
{
    private: CComPtr< IMyComClass > m_p_my_class;

    public: t_MyComClassWrapper(void)
    :    m_p_my_class(new CMyComClass)
    {}

    // TODO forward IMyComClass methods...
};

auto p_wrapper(::std::make_shared< t_MyComClassWrapper >());
```

This design will ensure that object won't be destroyed until both C++ and COM reference counters drop to 0.

Comment: Think of script or ATL code doing `CreateInstance()` or `new ActiveXObject("SomeClassId")' to create instance of the class, how the wrapper supposed to help here?

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg The idea is to keep com ptr to your COM class inside of wrapper, regardless of method actually used to create COM class instance. You can create it outside and then pass `CComPtr< IMyComClass >` into `t_MyComClassWrapper` constructor.

Comment: a) it will require change on the client side. b) IMyComClass is accessible from script/c#/ATL code which imported the library. The wrapper is not accessible, how do you want to pass your COM instance to the wrapper? BTW, check the question EDIT001